# Doctrine query crashing

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Very very weird. I have used this method from doctrine hundreds of times. I have a simple controller that takes an id as parameter. The query that Doctrine generates is wrong and crash.

```
/**
 * @Security("has_role('ROLE_ADMIN')")
 * @return Response
 */
public function editSellerAction($id)
{
    $em  = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $seller = $em->getRepository('SiteUserBundle:Seller')->find($id);

    // ...
    $form = $this->createForm(new SellerType(), $seller, array(
        'method' => 'POST'
    ));
    // ...
}
```

The query generated is the following

> [2/2] DBALException: An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t1.id AS id2, t1.username AS username3, t1.password AS password4, t1.firstname AS firstname5, t1.lastname AS lastname6 FROM seller t1 WHERE **t0**.id = ? LIMIT 1' with params ["2"]:

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't0.id' in 'where clause'   +

The error thrown makes sense because it's looking at "WHERE t0.id" when it should be looking at "WHERE t1.id". I tried the query with t1 using phpmyadmin and it works.

Any idea what might cause this issue?

```
/**
 * Seller have access to their customer and are able to RW access to the customers
 *
 * @ORM\Table("seller")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @author Michael Villeneuve
 */
class Seller extends User
{

    /**
     * @var array
     * 
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Customer", mappedBy="seller", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="seller_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    protected $customers; 

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="firstname", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $firstname;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="lastname", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $lastname;

    // Other attributes and only getters/setter


/**
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
     */
    private $password;
```

I have 3 entities that extends the User (customer, admin and seller).

Comment: can you add the entities you are referring to?

Comment: @byf-ferdy I can but it's like 100 lines long + it extends my user which is another 100 lines. Is there anything specific in the entity you would like to see?

Comment: The `id` would be interesting if it's is unusual. Other than that have you tried clearing the `cache`? Not much more I could think of.

Comment: By *extends my user* you mean you have a relation on database level? How are these two entities represented on mysql level?

Comment: Well now that you talk about it, it's the first time that I extend a Doctrine entity. So it's probably why I'm having an issue. Give me a minute I'll post what it looks like.

Comment: I edited with a sample of my User/Seller

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Updated link: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/inheritance-mapping.html

Read up a bit on mapped super classes: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html.  Basically, your abstract base user class cannot itself be an entity.

So take the @ORM\Entity line out of your User class.  That is where the table 0 (t0) is coming from.

Comment: This should be a solution to my problem. Please, check it in here.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47506319/application-works-in-app-dev-php-but-not-visible-using-app-php

Comment: Seems like link is dead @Cerad.

Comment: @JamshadAhmad Not surprised.  The latest docs now point to Doctrine 3.0 which is a complete (and unreleased as of this writing) rewrite.  I guess it's one reason link only answers are frowned upon.  But in this case, I did offer the actual solution.

Answer (score 2):

#### You have 2 options:

- The first one is to create an `abstract` **User** entity and *inherit* all values from it. This is useful if you have many entities with the same behaviour. I e.g. like to create a `BaseEntity` with a `ID` field and some basic *methods*. All entities can `extend` this one and automatically have an `ID`. Cerad explained [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21537949/1847340) how this is done.
- The second option are so called *discriminator fields*. Basically they allow you to have one `User` table and *sub-tables* for every extended entity. You can read about them in the [official docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html).

Which one you end up using is probably case dependent.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `id` field to the `Seller` entity instead of User

```
/**
 * Seller have access to their customer and are able to RW access to the customers
 *
 * @ORM\Table("seller")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Seller extends User
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var array
     * 
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Customer", mappedBy="seller", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="seller_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    protected $customers; 

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="firstname", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $firstname;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="lastname", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $lastname;

    // Other attributes and only getters/setter


/**
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @author Michael Villeneuve<michael@panierdachat.com>
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
     */
    private $password;
```

Comment: That should not be the solution. You can extend entities and their fields

Comment: But `id` doesn't inherit

Comment: The problem with 2 entities confusing the *DBAL* will still be persistent.